# iOS 8 and problems with iWork's accessing iCloud

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, iwork

I upgraded my iPad 3 to iOS 8.  Now, when I go to any iWorks app, my iCloud files do not show up.  However, my iCloud contacts, calendar, etc. are all perfectly fine, the problem seems to be localized to iWorks.  Further, the 'use iCloud' button in the each iWorks app settings will not stay on.  At the same time, the iWorks apps on my new iPhone 6 show the iCloud files.

I have tried resetting my iPad, as well as deleting and reinstalling the iWork apps.

Any ideas or suggestions?  What is going on?

Comment: Have you upgraded to iCloud Drive?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've inadvertently upgraded yourself to iCloud Drive via Pages for iOS on your iPhone, but not on your iPad.

To activate iCloud Drive on your iPad, follow these steps:

1. Go to the Home Screen.
2. Find and open Settings.
3. Scroll down to iCloud, and tap iCloud.
4. Tap iCloud Drive.
5. Toggle the switch to the right of the text "iCloud Drive" to the ON (green) position.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I checked my iPhone and iCloud Drive is set to off.  Further, I can see the iCloud files on my iMac, which presumably does not work with iCloud Drive.  So, I do not think that is the situation.